# Is there a way to extract .rpm file through windows batch file? Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: batch-file

1. Given: file1.rpm ( want to extract it to .cpio through batch script)
2. Extract file1.cpio

Need solution to this so that I can use the contents after extraction

Comment: Welcome. Stackoverflow is for Programming related questions. This question is not related to programming and therefore is off topic here. Please post on superuser.com instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) has the capability to extract files from an `.rpm`. Use the `e` option to extract.

```
7z e file1.rpm
```

Comment: You shouldn't down vote an answer because a question is off topic.

Comment: @BhaktiJoshi if by that you mean using a windows command line only with the default tools, no. However you can use the line that I posted on my answer in a batch file once you have installed 7zip.